# Set TraceId on Activity

Tags: .net-core, trace

I have a worker service which listens on a message broker and gets triggered when a message arrives. Once it is triggered I manually create an `Activity` and copy `SpanId` from the incoming message into the local `Activity.ParentID`. However, the local Trace Id is generated anew and I lose the ability to trace across services. I cannot manually copy the Trace Id over because `Activity.TraceId` is read only.

```
Activity.DefaultIdFormat = ActivityIdFormat.W3C;
using var activity = new Activity("Consumer");
activity.SetParentId(messageFromBroker.ParentId);
activity.Start();
_logger.LogInformation("foo foo foo");
// ... do some processing...
activity.Stop();
```

How can I create a new `Activity` and manually set `TraceId`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `TraceId` cannot be set explicitly, but what you can do is provide entire `traceparent` header, as below:

```
activity.SetParentId("00-0af7651916cd43dd8448eb211c80319c-b7ad6b7169203331-01");
```